# Replacing the id in the array with the name from the second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, ecmascript-6

I have some problem with connecting two arrays with objects by `id` and replace that `id` by `NAME` from second array. For example I have arrays:

```
array1 = [
  {id: [1, 2], info: "xxx"},
  {id: [2, 3], info: "yyy"}
]

array2 = [
  {nameId: 1, name: "Miami"},
  {nameId: 2, name: "Wacanda"},
  {nameId: 3, name: "London"},
]
```

And I want to modify `array1` or create new `array3` like (with use ES6):

```
array1 = [
  {id: ["Miami", "Wacanda"], info: "xxx"},
  {id: ["Wacanda", "London"], info: "yyy"}
]
```

or

```
array3 = [
  {name: ["Miami", "Wacanda"], info: "xxx"},
  {name: ["Wacanda", "London"], info: "yyy"}
]
```

Link to fast editing:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lrnfrd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftesting%2Ftesting.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to first generate a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) between the `ids` and the `names` from the `array2` using [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Then you can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the `array1` to get the desired data. Note in the next example I have choice your second sample of output.

```js
const array1 = [
  {id: [1, 2], info: "xxx"},
  {id: [2, 3], info: "yyy"}
];

const array2 = [
  {nameId: 1, name: "Miami"},
  {nameId: 2, name: "Wacanda"},
  {nameId: 3, name: "London"},
];

let nameFromId = array2.reduce(
    (acc, {nameId, name}) => (acc.set(nameId, name), acc),
    new Map()
);

let res = array1.map(({id, info}) => ({name: id.map(i => nameFromId.get(i)), info}));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Another alternative without generating a `Map` is to use [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) inside the `map()` function:

```
let res = array1.map(
  ({id, info}) => ({name: id.map(i => array2.find(o => o.nameId === i).name), info})
);
```

Comment: Thx for answer. I have only question if there is maybe solution without generete Map() with reduce. Maybe with use only methods f.e. forEach, filter, map, include?

Comment: Yes, there are other solutions without `Map`, you can replace that `Map` with an `object` using `ids` as the `keys` and the `names` as the `values`. The other alternative, with worse performace would be using [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) inside the `map()` function: `let res = array1.map(({id, info}) => ({name: id.map(i => array2.find(o => o.nameId === i).name), info}));`

Comment: I have one more question. How to do that if I have much bigger object? Not only with 2 property(id, info), but with 10 or more?

Comment: @mrKorny You can use spread syntax, something like: `let res = array1.map(({id, ...others}) => ({name: id.map(i => array2.find(o => o.nameId === i).name), ...others}));`

Answer (score 0):

Really simple - just use nested `map` with `find`:

```js
const array1 = [{id:[1,2],info:"xxx"},{id:[2,3],info:"yyy"}];
const array2 = [{nameId:1,name:"Miami"},{nameId:2,name:"Wacanda"},{nameId:3,name:"London"}];
const array3 = array1.map(({ id, info }) => ({ name: id.map(e => array2.find(({ nameId }) => nameId == e).name), info }));
console.log(array3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will generate your second example:

```
var array3 = array1.map(({ id, info }) => ({
    name: array2.filter(({ nameId }) => id.includes(nameId)).map(({ name }) => name),
    info
}));
```

First it filters on the nameId being in the list of ids from array1, then it runs map to just return the name. The expected output becomes:

```
[
    {"name":["Miami","Wacanda"],"info":"xxx"},
    {"name":["Wacanda","London"],"info":"yyy"}
]
```